# Curry Anonymous Function

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, currying

I am new to Haskell and functionall programming and am a little confused. Why can not I curry an anonymous function, or is it even possible?

I have the following piece of code:

```
largestDivisible :: (Integral a) => a -> a
largestDivisible x
    | x <= 0    = error "NOT A VALID VALUE"
    | otherwise = head (myFilter (f x) [x-1, x-2..1])
    where f x y= x `mod` y == 0
```

When I try to write it like this:

```
largestDivisible :: (Integral a) => a -> a
largestDivisible x
    | x <= 0    = error "NOT A VALID VALUE"
    | otherwise = head (myFilter (\ x y = x `mod` y == 0) [x-1, x-2..1])
```

Then I get the following error if I try to load it into the GHCi I get the following error:

```
ListStuff.hs:85:35: error:
• Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool’ with actual type ‘a -> Bool’
• The lambda expression ‘\ x y -> (mod x y == 0)’
  has two arguments,
  but its type ‘a -> Bool’ has only one
  In the first argument of ‘myFilter’, namely
    ‘(\ x y -> (mod x y == 0))’
  In the first argument of ‘head’, namely
    ‘(myFilter (\ x y -> (mod x y == 0)) [x - 1, x - 2 .. 1])’
• Relevant bindings include
    x :: a (bound at ListStuff.hs:83:19)
    largestDivisible' :: a -> a (bound at ListStuff.hs:83:1)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: Why did you use `myFilter` instead `filter`? And I think more appropriate is to use `find` instead `filter`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code

```
| otherwise = head (myFilter (f x) [x-1, x-2..1])
where f x y= x `mod` y == 0
```

is equivalent to

```
| otherwise = head (myFilter (f x) [x-1, x-2..1])
where f = \x y -> x `mod` y == 0
```

which is equivalent to

```
| otherwise = head (myFilter ((\x y -> x `mod` y == 0) x) [x-1, x-2..1])
                                                   -- ^^^
```

Note that the application of `x` still remains there! We can further simplify by applying the anonymous function (a beta step):

```
| otherwise = head (myFilter (\y -> x `mod` y == 0) [x-1, x-2..1])
```

Comment: To you second code fragment: Does the whitespace matter? Is there a difference to write `\ x ... `or `\x ...`?
Okay, I think I got the point. In the third code fragment I create a function, to which I pass x (the x which you marked) and then I pass the list. Thank you for this! Obviously the fourth code fragment would be the 'best' one.

Comment: @SparkMonkay `\ x` is the same of `\x`. The space inside `\x y` matters, of course, otherwise `\xy` takes variable `xy` as argument.

Comment: That is what I mean, `\ x y z` is the same as `\x y z`.

Answer (score 5):

`x` is an argument to `largestDivisible`, but you don't need to pass it as an argument to your lambda. The lambda can get `x` from the captured context, and only needs `y` as an argument.

The first version passes the partially-applied `f x`  to `myFilter`, and that - with the first argument given - is a unary function.

The second version tries passing a lambda of two arguments, without using partial application to get a suitable function first.

Either use partial application as in your first example, or just write a lambda of one argument (`y`).

Comment: I see it, thank you. It's sad that I did not took the x from the context and applied it to the function.